# DateTime supported language for formatting?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, globalization, culture

DateTime let you format depending of the current culture. What are the culture supported by default?

The scenario I have in mind use `this.Date.Value.ToString("MMMM")` which will print "January" if the culture is set to english-us but will print "Janvier" if the culture is in french-ca. This formatting documentation can be found at [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx) but doesn't give the scope of culture this one can translate.

I would like to know what languages are supported and if a language is not, what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CultureInfo.GetCultures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx) to get all supported cultures.

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
string allTranslatedJanuaries = 
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine, cultures.Select(c =>
        String.Format("{0}: {1}", c.EnglishName, c.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1))));
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/9CUjK

On my server 352 cultures are installed, upon ideone only 112.

Comment: That's a lot of Januaries (not sure if that's even a word :))

Comment: Does .NET also support multilingual abbreviations? i.e. "January" = "Jan" (English) or "Agosto" = "Ago" (spanish)...etc.

Comment: @series0ne: yes of course, you just need to provide the culture, by default your current culture is used. So for example: `DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM")` gives you the month name of your current culture. If you want to get a different, for example german: `var gerCult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM",gerCult);`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes, but that returns the translation of the entire word. i.e. (en-GB) "August" = (es-ES) "agosto". I want only the abbreviation. i.e. (en-GB) "Aug" = (es-ES) "ago". I know I can use Substring(0, 3), but my gut feeling is that this will not work for all languages.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, hi, just FYI (in case you didn't know), you can use "MMM", to get an abbreviation!! :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, and "ddd" for an abbreviated day name.

Comment: @series0ne: I know, but OP wanted the full month name. Edit: Now i understand your initial question, i have just read "multilingual" and overlooked "abbreviation" ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
Afrikaans( afr-af )
Afrikaans (South Africa)( afr-af )
Albanian( sqi-sq )
Albanian (Albania)( sqi-sq )
Alsatian( gsw-gsw )
Alsatian (France)( gsw-gsw )
Amharic( amh-am )
Amharic (Ethiopia)( amh-am )
Arabic( ara-ar )
Arabic (Algeria)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Bahrain)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Egypt)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Iraq)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Jordan)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Kuwait)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Lebanon)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Libya)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Morocco)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Oman)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Qatar)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Saudi Arabia)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Syria)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Tunisia)( ara-ar )
Arabic (U.A.E.)( ara-ar )
Arabic (Yemen)( ara-ar )
Armenian( hye-hy )
Armenian (Armenia)( hye-hy )
Assamese( asm-as )
Assamese (India)( asm-as )
Azeri( aze-az )
Azeri (Cyrillic)( aze-az )
Azeri (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan)( aze-az )
Azeri (Latin)( aze-az )
Azeri (Latin, Azerbaijan)( aze-az )
Bashkir( bak-ba )
Bashkir (Russia)( bak-ba )
Basque( eus-eu )
Basque (Basque)( eus-eu )
Belarusian( bel-be )
Belarusian (Belarus)( bel-be )
Bengali( bng-bn )
Bengali (Bangladesh)( bng-bn )
Bengali (India)( bng-bn )
Bosnian( bsb-bs )
Bosnian (Cyrillic)( bsc-bs )
Bosnian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)( bsc-bs )
Bosnian (Latin)( bsb-bs )
Bosnian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)( bsb-bs )
Breton( bre-br )
Breton (France)( bre-br )
Bulgarian( bul-bg )
Bulgarian (Bulgaria)( bul-bg )
Catalan( cat-ca )
Catalan (Catalan)( cat-ca )
Chinese( zho-zh )
Chinese (Simplified)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Simplified) Legacy( zho-zh )
Chinese (Simplified, PRC)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Simplified, Singapore)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Traditional)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Traditional) Legacy( zho-zh )
Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong S.A.R.)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Traditional, Macao S.A.R.)( zho-zh )
Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)( zho-zh )
Corsican( cos-co )
Corsican (France)( cos-co )
Croatian( hrv-hr )
Croatian (Croatia)( hrv-hr )
Croatian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)( hrb-hr )
Czech( ces-cs )
Czech (Czech Republic)( ces-cs )
Danish( dan-da )
Danish (Denmark)( dan-da )
Dari( prs-prs )
Dari (Afghanistan)( prs-prs )
Divehi( div-dv )
Divehi (Maldives)( div-dv )
Dutch( nld-nl )
Dutch (Belgium)( nld-nl )
Dutch (Netherlands)( nld-nl )
English( eng-en )
English (Australia)( eng-en )
English (Belize)( eng-en )
English (Canada)( eng-en )
English (Caribbean)( eng-en )
English (India)( eng-en )
English (Ireland)( eng-en )
English (Jamaica)( eng-en )
English (Malaysia)( eng-en )
English (New Zealand)( eng-en )
English (Republic of the Philippines)( eng-en )
English (Singapore)( eng-en )
English (South Africa)( eng-en )
English (Trinidad and Tobago)( eng-en )
English (United Kingdom)( eng-en )
English (United States)( eng-en )
English (Zimbabwe)( eng-en )
Estonian( est-et )
Estonian (Estonia)( est-et )
Faroese( fao-fo )
Faroese (Faroe Islands)( fao-fo )
Filipino( fil-fil )
Filipino (Philippines)( fil-fil )
Finnish( fin-fi )
Finnish (Finland)( fin-fi )
French( fra-fr )
French (Belgium)( fra-fr )
French (Canada)( fra-fr )
French (France)( fra-fr )
French (Luxembourg)( fra-fr )
French (Monaco)( fra-fr )
French (Switzerland)( fra-fr )
Frisian( fry-fy )
Frisian (Netherlands)( fry-fy )
Galician( glg-gl )
Galician (Galician)( glg-gl )
Georgian( kat-ka )
Georgian (Georgia)( kat-ka )
German( deu-de )
German (Austria)( deu-de )
German (Germany)( deu-de )
German (Liechtenstein)( deu-de )
German (Luxembourg)( deu-de )
German (Switzerland)( deu-de )
Greek( ell-el )
Greek (Greece)( ell-el )
Greenlandic( kal-kl )
Greenlandic (Greenland)( kal-kl )
Gujarati( guj-gu )
Gujarati (India)( guj-gu )
Hausa( hau-ha )
Hausa (Latin)( hau-ha )
Hausa (Latin, Nigeria)( hau-ha )
Hebrew( heb-he )
Hebrew (Israel)( heb-he )
Hindi( hin-hi )
Hindi (India)( hin-hi )
Hungarian( hun-hu )
Hungarian (Hungary)( hun-hu )
Icelandic( isl-is )
Icelandic (Iceland)( isl-is )
Igbo( ibo-ig )
Igbo (Nigeria)( ibo-ig )
Indonesian( ind-id )
Indonesian (Indonesia)( ind-id )
Inuktitut( iku-iu )
Inuktitut (Latin)( iku-iu )
Inuktitut (Latin, Canada)( iku-iu )
Inuktitut (Syllabics)( iku-iu )
Inuktitut (Syllabics, Canada)( iku-iu )
Invariant Language (Invariant Country)( ivl-iv )
Irish( gle-ga )
Irish (Ireland)( gle-ga )
isiXhosa( xho-xh )
isiXhosa (South Africa)( xho-xh )
isiZulu( zul-zu )
isiZulu (South Africa)( zul-zu )
Italian( ita-it )
Italian (Italy)( ita-it )
Italian (Switzerland)( ita-it )
Japanese( jpn-ja )
Japanese (Japan)( jpn-ja )
Kannada( kan-kn )
Kannada (India)( kan-kn )
Kazakh( kaz-kk )
Kazakh (Kazakhstan)( kaz-kk )
Khmer( khm-km )
Khmer (Cambodia)( khm-km )
K'iche( qut-qut )
K'iche (Guatemala)( qut-qut )
Kinyarwanda( kin-rw )
Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)( kin-rw )
Kiswahili( swa-sw )
Kiswahili (Kenya)( swa-sw )
Konkani( kok-kok )
Konkani (India)( kok-kok )
Korean( kor-ko )
Korean (Korea)( kor-ko )
Kyrgyz( kir-ky )
Kyrgyz (Kyrgyzstan)( kir-ky )
Lao( lao-lo )
Lao (Lao P.D.R.)( lao-lo )
Latvian( lav-lv )
Latvian (Latvia)( lav-lv )
Lithuanian( lit-lt )
Lithuanian (Lithuania)( lit-lt )
Lower Sorbian( dsb-dsb )
Lower Sorbian (Germany)( dsb-dsb )
Luxembourgish( ltz-lb )
Luxembourgish (Luxembourg)( ltz-lb )
Macedonian (Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia)( mkd-mk )
Macedonian (FYROM)( mkd-mk )
Malay( msa-ms )
Malay (Brunei Darussalam)( msa-ms )
Malay (Malaysia)( msa-ms )
Malayalam( mym-ml )
Malayalam (India)( mym-ml )
Maltese( mlt-mt )
Maltese (Malta)( mlt-mt )
Maori( mri-mi )
Maori (New Zealand)( mri-mi )
Mapudungun( arn-arn )
Mapudungun (Chile)( arn-arn )
Marathi( mar-mr )
Marathi (India)( mar-mr )
Mohawk( moh-moh )
Mohawk (Mohawk)( moh-moh )
Mongolian( mon-mn )
Mongolian (Cyrillic)( mon-mn )
Mongolian (Cyrillic, Mongolia)( mon-mn )
Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian)( mon-mn )
Mongolian (Traditional Mongolian, PRC)( mon-mn )
Nepali( nep-ne )
Nepali (Nepal)( nep-ne )
Norwegian( nob-nb )
Norwegian (Bokmål)( nob-nb )
Norwegian (Nynorsk)( nno-nn )
Norwegian, Bokmål (Norway)( nob-nb )
Norwegian, Nynorsk (Norway)( nno-nn )
Occitan( oci-oc )
Occitan (France)( oci-oc )
Oriya( ori-or )
Oriya (India)( ori-or )
Pashto( pus-ps )
Pashto (Afghanistan)( pus-ps )
Persian( fas-fa )
Persian( fas-fa )
Polish( pol-pl )
Polish (Poland)( pol-pl )
Portuguese( por-pt )
Portuguese (Brazil)( por-pt )
Portuguese (Portugal)( por-pt )
Punjabi( pan-pa )
Punjabi (India)( pan-pa )
Quechua( qub-quz )
Quechua (Bolivia)( qub-quz )
Quechua (Ecuador)( que-quz )
Quechua (Peru)( qup-quz )
Romanian( ron-ro )
Romanian (Romania)( ron-ro )
Romansh( roh-rm )
Romansh (Switzerland)( roh-rm )
Russian( rus-ru )
Russian (Russia)( rus-ru )
Sami (Inari)( smn-smn )
Sami (Lule)( smk-smj )
Sami (Northern)( sme-se )
Sami (Skolt)( sms-sms )
Sami (Southern)( smb-sma )
Sami, Inari (Finland)( smn-smn )
Sami, Lule (Norway)( smj-smj )
Sami, Lule (Sweden)( smk-smj )
Sami, Northern (Finland)( smg-se )
Sami, Northern (Norway)( sme-se )
Sami, Northern (Sweden)( smf-se )
Sami, Skolt (Finland)( sms-sms )
Sami, Southern (Norway)( sma-sma )
Sami, Southern (Sweden)( smb-sma )
Sanskrit( san-sa )
Sanskrit (India)( san-sa )
Scottish Gaelic( gla-gd )
Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom)( gla-gd )
Serbian( srp-sr )
Serbian (Cyrillic)( srp-sr )
Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)( srn-sr )
Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)( srp-sr )
Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia and Montenegro (Former))( srp-sr )
Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)( srp-sr )
Serbian (Latin)( srp-sr )
Serbian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)( srs-sr )
Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)( srp-sr )
Serbian (Latin, Serbia and Montenegro (Former))( srp-sr )
Serbian (Latin, Serbia)( srp-sr )
Sesotho sa Leboa( nso-nso )
Sesotho sa Leboa (South Africa)( nso-nso )
Setswana( tsn-tn )
Setswana (South Africa)( tsn-tn )
Sinhala( sin-si )
Sinhala (Sri Lanka)( sin-si )
Slovak( slk-sk )
Slovak (Slovakia)( slk-sk )
Slovenian( slv-sl )
Slovenian (Slovenia)( slv-sl )
Spanish( spa-es )
Spanish (Argentina)( spa-es )
Spanish (Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela)( spa-es )
Spanish (Bolivia)( spa-es )
Spanish (Chile)( spa-es )
Spanish (Colombia)( spa-es )
Spanish (Costa Rica)( spa-es )
Spanish (Dominican Republic)( spa-es )
Spanish (Ecuador)( spa-es )
Spanish (El Salvador)( spa-es )
Spanish (Guatemala)( spa-es )
Spanish (Honduras)( spa-es )
Spanish (Mexico)( spa-es )
Spanish (Nicaragua)( spa-es )
Spanish (Panama)( spa-es )
Spanish (Paraguay)( spa-es )
Spanish (Peru)( spa-es )
Spanish (Puerto Rico)( spa-es )
Spanish (Spain)( spa-es )
Spanish (United States)( spa-es )
Spanish (Uruguay)( spa-es )
Swedish( swe-sv )
Swedish (Finland)( swe-sv )
Swedish (Sweden)( swe-sv )
Syriac( syr-syr )
Syriac (Syria)( syr-syr )
Tajik( tgk-tg )
Tajik (Cyrillic)( tgk-tg )
Tajik (Cyrillic, Tajikistan)( tgk-tg )
Tamazight( tzm-tzm )
Tamazight (Latin)( tzm-tzm )
Tamazight (Latin, Algeria)( tzm-tzm )
Tamil( tam-ta )
Tamil (India)( tam-ta )
Tatar( tat-tt )
Tatar (Russia)( tat-tt )
Telugu( tel-te )
Telugu (India)( tel-te )
Thai( tha-th )
Thai (Thailand)( tha-th )
Tibetan( bod-bo )
Tibetan (PRC)( bod-bo )
Turkish( tur-tr )
Turkish (Turkey)( tur-tr )
Turkmen( tuk-tk )
Turkmen (Turkmenistan)( tuk-tk )
Ukrainian( ukr-uk )
Ukrainian (Ukraine)( ukr-uk )
Upper Sorbian( hsb-hsb )
Upper Sorbian (Germany)( hsb-hsb )
Urdu( urd-ur )
Urdu (Islamic Republic of Pakistan)( urd-ur )
Uyghur( uig-ug )
Uyghur (PRC)( uig-ug )
Uzbek( uzb-uz )
Uzbek (Cyrillic)( uzb-uz )
Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan)( uzb-uz )
Uzbek (Latin)( uzb-uz )
Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan)( uzb-uz )
Vietnamese( vie-vi )
Vietnamese (Vietnam)( vie-vi )
Welsh( cym-cy )
Welsh (United Kingdom)( cym-cy )
Wolof( wol-wo )
Wolof (Senegal)( wol-wo )
Yakut( sah-sah )
Yakut (Russia)( sah-sah )
Yi( iii-ii )
Yi (PRC)( iii-ii )
Yoruba( yor-yo )
Yoruba (Nigeria)( yor-yo )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine all languages that the OS supports (considering that is where the information comes from).

Here is a list of all [default supported languages by OS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The set of supported cultures will be the set of [custom cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx) that have been installed on the box plus the set of predefined cultures (for .Net 3.5 and below or Vista and below this is a fixed set, but for .Net 4 and above on Win7 and above, this is predefined cultures for the OS that it is running on).

If a language isn't supported, you can create a custom culture. This does require admin privilege to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your culture like this:

Set the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to a new culture, e.g. to set to French:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

and after your date format, and month name will be french.

You can choose from these [Cultures](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

Comment: -1 He knows how to change the culture, he is asking for the scope of the language translation.

Comment: Understood, I've added another line.